# steady states and stability mathematical biology

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

could anyone help on how to do this please?

find the steady states of $$F(N)=\frac{rN}{1+N}.$$

do you differentiate and set it equal to zero and find $N$?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate the steady state and what $F(N)$ denotes?

Comment: $F(N) = \frac{dN}{dt}$

Comment: $N$? This seems to be a application of math in bio. You can just tell what is steady state (what is it??) any extreme case would be found by differentiation......

Comment: the steady states- you have to put back into the differential of $F(N)$ and decided whether they are stable or not, i know how to do this just need some confirmation on finding the steady states. many thanks

Comment: So, that is linear ODE ? which need's to be solved?

Comment: it is math bio- just in more extreme cases i would need to do it the long way, so i would do it the longer way even for simpler equations such as this. am i right in my question about what i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A steady state is one which stays the same when put into the function. So you want $N^*$ satisfying
$$ \frac{rN^*}{1 + N^*} = F(N^*) = N^*,$$
or $(1+N^*)N^* = rN^*$. So $N^*$, your steady state, is a root of the quadratic
$x^2 + (1-r)x = 0$. Then your two solutions are $x=0$ (which corresponds to a population of size $0$) and $x = r-1$.

Comment: so if the question was $F(N)=rN(1-N^2)$ would the steady states be $\pm\sqrt{\frac{r-1}{r}}$?

Comment: Yes. In that case you would get a cubic with three steady states because $F(N^*) = N^*$ implies $r(N^*)^3 + (1- r)N^* = 0$. Then $N^*$ is a solution of that cubic, which has roots $x=0$, and, as you pointed out, $\pm \sqrt{\frac{r}{r-1}}$. However, if this is a population model you should discard the negative values of $N$.

Comment: i have come across a difficult one which i cant seem to solve- $F(N)=rN(1-\frac{N}{q})-\frac{N}{1+N}$ any help on this aswell would be much appreciated, ive tried the same technique but doesnt seem to be simple at all. im very thankful for your help it is much appreciated

Comment: This example has you solving $rN(1-\frac{N}{q})-\frac{N}{1+N} - N = 0$. Multiply through by $1+N$ to get a cubic, and then you can factor out an $N$ (corresponding to a root at $N=0$) to give you a quadratic equation which is easy to solve.

Comment: would the equation be: $\frac{-(1-r+\frac{r}{q}) \pm \sqrt{(1-r+\frac{r}{q})^2 - 4(\frac{r}{q})(2-r)}}{2(\frac{r}{q})}$?

Comment: Yes: you would get (after multiplication by $N+1$), $rN(N+1)(1 - \frac{N}{q}) - N - N(N+1) = 0$, from which you can factor out an $N$ to get the solutions $N=0$ and $r(1 + (1 - \frac{1}{q})N - \frac{N^2}{q}) - 1 - (N+1) = 0$. The latter equation implies that $N$ is a solution of the quadratic $ \frac{r}{q}x^2+(1-r(1 - \frac{1}{q}))x + 2 - r = 0$. The roots are $$\frac{-1+r(1-1/q) \pm \sqrt{(1 - r(1-1/q))^2 - 4r(2-r)/q}}{2r/q}$$